# Error code:0x80071A90 - When Installing IIS on Windows 10.1

Tags: windows

I get this error: Windows couldn't complete the requested changes. The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction.Error code:0x80071A90, when I trying to install IIS on windows 10 Pro.

May you kindly assist in resolving this issue.

Kindest Regards
Lucky

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forum post which suggests a reboot and then if not resolved, using the dism command - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1e884a30-0c3b-48fa-9dc1-0e22167472df/unable-to-install-iis-manager-on-windows-8-home-edition?forum=w8itprogeneral